# Instagram display public hashtag content in a website

Tags: web, hashtag

I am seeking for a solution to display public content by specific hashtag in my client's website for an event(short period of time), what is the alternative solution I have as I know Instagram is not allow to do this anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Intsagram web call thr search there with the hashtag you want and then parse the HTML and collect thr searchresults ;)
But isn't there a official API for this?